# Integrate Emacs copy/paste with System copy/paste

Tags: linux, emacs, copy-paste, gnome

I have (cua-mode t) in my .emacs, so that C-c is copy and C-v is paste just like most other programs on my desktop (Ubuntu, Gnome, Linux). However, Emacs does not seem to share the clipboard/copy buffer with other programs.

For example, if I C-c in Firefox I can S-C-v to paste into a terminal or C-v to paste into gedit. However, if I C-v (or C-y) in emacs, I do not get what I copied from Firefox.

Is there any way to make this work? Is there another command I can use to access the system's copy-paste buffer?

Comment: It does share a clipboard with system by the way, but only mouse selection (i.e. what you can paste with a middle-click elsewhere).

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superuser.com?

Comment: Vim and Emacs questions are generally considered ok for SO as they're programmer's tools.  See the various discussions that have already taken place about this on meta.

Comment: @jamessan Ok, I agree :)

Comment: @doublep yes it does seem to use X11 selection buffer, but it doesn't seem to use the clipboard by default. So selecting and middle click work, but copy-paste key-commands don't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works on my machine:

```
;; CUA OS copypasta even in ncurses mode
(case system-type
  ('darwin (unless window-system
             (setq interprogram-cut-function
                   (lambda (text &optional push)
                     (let* ((process-connection-type nil)
                            (pbproxy (start-process "pbcopy" "pbcopy" "/usr/bin/pbcopy")))
                       (process-send-string pbproxy text)
                       (process-send-eof pbproxy))))))
  ('gnu/linux (progn
                (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
                (defun xsel-cut-function (text &optional push)
                  (with-temp-buffer
                    (insert text)
                    (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "xsel" nil 0 nil "--clipboard" "--input")))
                (defun xsel-paste-function()

                  (let ((xsel-output (shell-command-to-string "xsel --clipboard --output")))
                    (unless (string= (car kill-ring) xsel-output)
                      xsel-output )))
                (setq interprogram-cut-function 'xsel-cut-function)
                (setq interprogram-paste-function 'xsel-paste-function))))
```

Comment: Nice! This works for C-c/C-x/C-v, but now middle click doesn't share with the system any more. Does middle click still work for you?

Comment: this only works in the emacs window mode rather than the terminal (-nw) mode, right?

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. I added this to my .emacs file:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

Now Ctrl-C and Ctrl-v between Emacs and other applications work fine.
Source: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-310237.html)

Comment: Ah, even better. I only had the first command. But the second helps a problem I'd had, where selecting text and middle clicking in emacs did not copy correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I am newbie. I created ~/.emacs for the first time. I added your code to ~/.emacs and it works. Thanks.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for Mac OSX; Getting this error. `current-kill: Symbol's function definition is void: x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value`

Comment: I was missing `'` before both those lines when added to `emacs.el`

Comment: This does not work for me using Ubuntu 16.04 and Emacs 24. Copying text outside of terminal Emacs and then pasting (or clipboard-yank) inside Emacs doesn't retrieve the right text, even with this enabled.

Answer (score 15):

See `clipboard-yank` and `clipboard-kill-region` in the [clipboard](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html#Clipboard) section of the manual.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. I added (x-select-enable-clipboard t) to my .emacs file and everything is working like I'd expect.

Thank you.

Comment: Hm, actually, this isn't exactly right. This will paste from X11 selections. But it's a lot better than it was.

Comment: This is sometimes bound to just `paste` (at least in Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste#toc5) page will help, especially the section where `clipboard-kill-region`, `clipboard-kill-ring-save`, and `clipboard-yank` are mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @danlei, the wiki had some useful advice.

Comment: You're welcome. EmacsWiki is a great source for everything concerning Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with `autocutsel`, which works with `emacs` and the rest of my Ubuntu system too.

> ```
>   autocutsel - keep the X clipboard and the cutbuffer in sync
> ```

I use the following commands (run once, usually invoked by my window manager's "startup" mechanism, or `~/.xsession`):

```
autocutsel -fork
autocutsel -fork -selection PRIMARY
```

The first instance of `autocutsel` does the following:

> autocutsel tracks changes in the [X11] server's cutbuffer and clipboard selection.  When the clipboard is
>   changed, it updates the cutbuffer.  When the cutbuffer is changed, it owns the clipboard selection.  The
>   cutbuffer and clipboard selection are always synchronized.

However there's usually a third clipboard, called `PRIMARY`, which the second instance of `autocutsel` is used to sync with the other two.

The advantages of this are that the three main clipboards are unified, so that pasting current selection via middle-click or CUA-style copy/paste with CTRL-C and CTRL-V all work together.

The main downside of this approach is that any automatic highlighting of text (such as double-clicking to highlight a word in emacs, or clicking the BlockQuote icon in a StackOverflow edit field) will obliterate your copy buffer instantly. To work around this, I use a clipboard history recorder such as `glipper`, which also conveniently records all clipboard content and allows me to retrieve lost clipboard contents in such circumstances. It can take a little getting-used-to and works well for me. As an alternative, you could experiment with the `-pause` option, which waits for some period of time before taking the selection, which may be long enough to deselect or delete any auto-selected text. I wasn't able to get results that worked well enough for me, though.

Note that this solution doesn't require any special `emacs` configuration, which I use with cua-mode enabled.