# Cua-copy/paste and System clipboard in emacs

Tags: emacs

I've set this in emacs:

```lisp
    (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

And it works just fine.

That is, until I copy something from within emacs using cua-copy (bound to C-c).
Then, whenever I try to copy something from other programs and paste it into emacs, it keeps pasting the same entry it last copied using cua-copy.

The clipboard itself still works - the same entry is pasted regularly in any other program.

So far I tried defining several things but to no avail:

```lisp
(setq x-select-enable-primary nil)                               
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)                               
(setq select-active-regions t)                                   
(global-set-key [mouse-2] 'mouse-yank-primary)                   
(setq yank-pop-change-selection t)                               
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

Only when I forcefully paste from the clipboard using the command x-clipboard-yank does it resolve to its proper state, until I use cua-copy again.

Did anyone Ever encountered such a problem, or have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about Emacs to offer any insights, but I can share what works for me (on Ubuntu) since i  also have copy/paste bound to C-c/C-v with this in my ~/.emacs:

```
(cua-mode t)
```

And per this post: [Integrate Emacs copy/paste with System copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216081/integrate-emacs-copy-paste-with-system-copy-paste) I have copying and pasting to/from Emacs without the problem you describe with these lines in ~/.emacs:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

I see you already tried the two lines above, but did you try them alone without the other lines which might be conflicting with them?

Answer (score 1):

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14819945) doesn't work for Emacs **24**. Adding these lines to my `.emacs` is what worked for me:

```
(setq select-active-regions nil)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region t)
```

Comment: Nice, the sooner the better.

Comment: @Carlos Strange, works as seamlessly for me in Emacs 24 as it did in Emacs 23.

Comment: I don't know but the selected answer didn't work for me and it was driving me crazy! I spent several hours looking for a solution until I found my proposed answer [here](http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-how-to-to-combine-emacs-primary-clipboard-copy-and-paste-behavior-on-ms-windows-13036155.html). So I thought it could be useful for someone else :)