# Using X11 clipboard in Emacs instance inside gnome-terminal

Tags: emacs, x11, copy-paste, kill-ring

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 from the Gnome Terminal in Arch Linux. When I copy text from outside the Gnome Terminal window (from any other X window, e.g. Firefox), it is not available in the Emacs kill-ring. I have tried `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)` to no avail.

I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216081/integrate-emacs-copy-paste-with-system-copy-paste), which did not work.

Note: this functionality works when Emacs is run graphically; I am only having a problem when I run Emacs inside a terminal window.

Comment: Found a [solution] (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/412/copy-and-paste-between-emacs-in-an-x-terminal-and-other-x-applications) (albeit a messy one) to my problem hiding on the new emacs stackexchange page (didn't show up when I searched).

Answer (score 3):

The development version of Emacs supports the so-called OSC-52 escape sequences which are supported by some terminals to let applications running inside the terminal access the clipboard.

Sadly, this OSC-52 feature can be (as currently designed in xterms) somewhat dangerous in some situations (e.g. if you display, via `cat`, in your terminal a file written by someone else), so most of the distributions have disabled the feature by default.

But least for me, under Debian testing, running Emacs-25 inside an `xterm -xrm '*.allowWindowOps: true'` lets me set the X clipboard via `C-k` just as if the Emacs was running in GUI mode.

Emacs also supports the direction you want (i.e. makes `C-y` in Emacs get the text from the X clipboard), tho you'll have to additionally add `getSelection` to your `xterm-extra-capabilities` in your `~/.emacs`.